# Move the screen up when keyboard appears depending of the textView. Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I've tried to move the screen up when keyboard appears. I did it with success but I need to know how to scroll the view only when de bottom `UITextView` is clicked, and not with the top `TextView` because keyboard just touches the `TextView` below.

App is this:

[Our view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuPyX.png)

```
class viewControllerCuatro: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

 @IBOutlet weak var textViewInteriorUno: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var textViewInteriorDos: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {


self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Atrás", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)


**NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: self.view.window)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: self.view.window)**




}


 **func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {**



// 1
let userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject] = sender.userInfo!
// 2
let keyboardSize: CGSize = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]!.CGRectValue.size
let offset: CGSize = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]!.CGRectValue.size
// 3
if keyboardSize.height == offset.height {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
    })
} else {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height - offset.height
    })
    }


}

**func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification)** {
let userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject] = sender.userInfo!
let keyboardSize: CGSize = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]!.CGRectValue.size
self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
}

**override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool)** {
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: self.view.window)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: self.view.window)
}


  override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

if textViewInteriorUno.text == ""  || textViewInteriorUno.text.isEmpty == true || textViewInteriorDos.text == "" || textViewInteriorDos.text.isEmpty == true {


    textViewInteriorUno.resignFirstResponder()


    textViewInteriorDos.resignFirstResponder()
}
else{

    self.textViewInteriorUno.resignFirstResponder()

    self.textViewInteriorDos.resignFirstResponder()
}
}

   func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool{

var shouldReplace = true // For most cases, return true, only modify if we have a special case

// If the textView is 'textViewInteriorUno'
if textView.isEqual(textViewInteriorUno) {

let newLength = textViewInteriorUno.text.utf16.count + text.utf16.count - range.length
shouldReplace = newLength <= 12           // will be true if the length is <= 12

}

else if textView.isEqual(textViewInteriorDos) {

let newLength = textViewInteriorDos.text.utf16.count + text.utf16.count - range.length
shouldReplace = newLength < 13 // Will be true if the length > 6


}

return shouldReplace
}
```

Comment: TPKeyboardavoiding for scrollview is the best library for Keyboard appear and Disappear

Comment: use this https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager , thank me later

Answer (score 11):

IQKeyboardManager was a godsend for me!

Step 1:

All you have to do is download the project from https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager and move the IQKeyboardManagerSwift directory from the demo project to your project.

Make sure the IQKeyboardManagerSwift directory is the right location in your project once you move it.

Step 2:

Then In AppDelegate.swift, just enable IQKeyboardManager in your application function.

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool 
  {

  // This is the only line of code you need to manually add
  // in order for IQKeybaordManager to work. Thats it.
  IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true

  return true
  }
}
```

That's it! Now your keyboard will slide up and move the view accordingly. Props to the creator of this framework, makes our lives a lot easier.